# What does this regex do? Why use it?

Tags: android, regex, text, floating-point

I'm doing some code maintenance at work, and I ran across this little snippet...

```
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start,
                int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            if (end > start) {
                String destTxt = dest.toString();
                String resultingTxt = destTxt.substring(0, dstart) + source.subSequence(start, end) + destTxt.substring(dend);

                try {
                    if (!resultingTxt.matches("[0123456789]*[.]?[0123456789]{0,2}")||
                            Float.parseFloat(resultingTxt)>360f) {
                        if (source instanceof Spanned) {
                            SpannableString sp = new SpannableString("");
                            return sp;
                        } else {
                            return "";
                        }

                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    // doesn't matter.
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Now I am not a reg ex expert, but it seems to me like this is a very verbose way of checking if a text box is not empty, contains a number between 0 and 360, with no more than 2 decimal precision, and which doesn't contain text.  Am I missing something?  This comes out of an android EditText.

Next part - Why in the name of the lord would you do this, rather than forcing the text to be number only, and using Double.parseDouble() or some equivalent?  Is the regex that much faster that its worth it?

This code is a mess, so I wouldn't be suprised if this guy had been reading - http://freeworld.thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html

Comment: Someone thought that he is very clever when writing this...

Comment: Use your best instincts, if you think code is stupid then change it, you can always roll back later if you were mistaken.  Source control ftw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in assuming that all the regex does is affirm that the input is a number, is not empty, and has no more than 2 decimal places.

No, there is no reason regex should be used in this place instead of `Double.parseDouble()`. In fact, in a quick test I threw together, 10,000 iterations of the regex took ~5 times longer (348ms) than the `Double.parseDouble()` format (71ms). Plus, he calls a parse on the number ANYWAY, to check if it's `> 360f`. Why? Who knows.

The coder here was either trying to get a job done quickly, or didn't understand Java well. My guess is the latter, but I hope it was the former.

*PS: That was an awesome link. Made my day. :)*

Comment: Glad you liked the link - your answer has my co-worker and I laughing quite hard as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can test out hard regular expressions on online tools , for example this cool website:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 1):

> [0123456789]*

Digits. The brackets tells us that "any one of these will do". The star at end says that it can be repeated in any amount (zero or more).

> [.]?

Again, the brackets says "any of these". It could be removed (there's only one option), however the dot "." also has meaning in regular expressions if it happen outside the brackets: it means "ANY char will do". To use a dot as a character, it should be escaped (perhaps "\.?"). The "?" tells us that this may happen one or zero times. Inside the brackets the dot doesn't behave as a meta-character.

> [0123456789]{0,2}

The curly brackets tell us the range of how many repeats of the same pattern as before could be done. {n,m} can be read as "repeats at least n times but no more than m times". This says that the text can have from no extra digit up to 2 extra digits.

Answer (score 0):

The regex (the only part I can answer with certainty) doesn't do what the author intended it to do. Basically, it checks that the string is any number of digits, then 0 or 1 of *any* character and then 0 to 2 integer digits.

Valid strings would include

```
1234567H12
q2
&
```

etc. If the writer had intended a dot to be matched, that portion of the regex should have read:

```
[\.]?
```

It also matches the empty string.

Comment: Actually, not in the Java regex engine. `System.out.println("5a6".matches("[0123456789]*[.]?[0123456789]{0,2}"))` prints out `false`.